# Macros to Send attach different files to multiple individual emails, vba

Tags: excel, vba, email, pdf

I am a computer technician, not a programmer, but in my new job I have been asked to finish a macros in excel (vba).
It consists of a list of id card numbers in one of the columns (the number of cells is variable each time it is used, one day you can put 20 people and another 12 for example), and emails in another column.
In a folder there are some pdf documents whose name is the id card of the person that appears in the excel.

What they ask me is that, being ordered the id card in alphabetical order, take the id card and email. The id card will serve to find your corresponding pdf and add it as an attachment with the idea of sending it by email, to whom? there the cell is used with the email data. This has to be done with each of the existing rows, take pdf file to attach it and send email to the address of that same row until there are no more rows on the sheet.

Can someone tell me how to do that or tell me the functions I need?

Thank you.

Graphical idea:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The macro is currently set to `.Display` the email and not send. After you have finished running tests you will want to change this to `.Send` to actually send the email.

You will also need to update the value of `strLocation`. Inside the quotes is where you will need to put the location of the folder that houses all of your target PDFs.

The order of your cells doesn't matter here as long as each row is associated to one individual.

Hopefully these emails are internal - you should not use this for external mailing lists as you cannot offer the option to unsubscribe. Outlook may flag/ban your account if you are suspected of spam.

This assumes the values in `Column C` are actual email addresses that will be recognized as is by Outlook. (*urdearboy@email.com*)

---

```
Sub CorpCard()

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim cell As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

On Error GoTo cleanup

For Each cell In Columns("C").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" Then
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail
            .SentOnBehalfOfName = "[your associated Outlook email here]"
            .to = cell.Value
                .Subject = "Subject goes here"
                .Body = "Hi " & Range("B" & cell.Row).Value & "," _

                'Body to be patsed here

            strLocation = "C:\Users\urdearboy\Desktop\File Name\" & Cells(cell.Row, "D").Value & ".pdf"
            .Attachments.Add (strLocation)
        .Display
        '.Send
        End With

        On Error GoTo 0
        Set OutMail = Nothing
    End If
Next cell

cleanup:
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @urdearboy,
Thanks by your help, I will try it monday in job.

To use the corporate emails system I read that I need Collaboration Data Objects (CDO) for windows 2000 library, It's this right? If that is the case, I will seek information about it. Thanks again!

Comment: I use this macro pretty often as is

Comment: Hi @urdearboy , I was referring to not using a mail client, for example as outlook, but to configure the parameters of the outgoing mail server of my own company in the macros itself, and what I found is that I have to use CDO.
I'm adapting what you gave me. :-)

Comment: Hi @urdearboy I'm near to finish my code:
[link](https://github.com/arv187/vba/blob/master/test)
But I'm having problems to do a counter (I think that sintaxys errors or I'm missing something).
wscript.shell Popup is working, show a message for 1 second for each email, but I need show "i"/total content rows for example:
email nº 1/30 send to john@doe.com
email nº 2/30 send to bob@doe.com
...

Comment: The last thing that I did was count the total rows used, but I don't know how skip the header (row1) or best, count rows from specific column (emails) in other Worksheet (I have two workseets, one is the table from my first message and other and the second worksheet contain all macros buttons and email config parameters). Thank you in advance!